# Automatically switch keyboard to match language of surrounding text

Tags: system-language

Is there a functionality in some Windows Writing applications that changes keyboard layout. like this:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/turn-on-automatic-language-options-HA010354274.aspx#_Toc311028922

Is there a simiar functionlity in Ubuntu or any ubuntu sotfware. I'm looking for any add-on or an option that activates such a functionality in LibreOffice.

Someone said linux softwares cannot change keyboard layout because a linux OS is kind of autocratic about system options and keyboard layout. But I think it is possible because plasma desktop does it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is an operating system, it manages your software, your files, your internet connection. An operating system doesn't have a particular natural language associated, it rather has an interface that can be rendered with multiple languages. Ubuntu is perfectly able to manage multiple keyboard layouts, but the concept of "surround text" does not apply to an operating system or its interface.

The request you make only makes sense within a particular text editing program such as gedit. The best thing to do is contact the support of the particular software.